# Given N identical resistors, find the total number of series-parallel combinations (different question). please read description

Tags: combinatorics

There are multiple answers that state that the total number of equivalent resistances possible are the number of partitions of $N$.

But what I am looking at is the **number of ways** to combine the resistances.

For example, take $N = 4$.

1. All 4 resistors can be in series..
2. 3 resistors can be in parallel, with that combination in series with
   the fourth resistance.
3. 2 resistors can be in series, in parallel with the third, which is in
   parallel with the fourth.
4. 2 resistors can be in series, and this in parallel with another 2 resistances in series.
5. 2 resistors can be in parallel, in series with another 2 resistances in parallel.
6. 3 resistors can be in series, with this combination in parallel with the fourth resistance.
7. 2 resistances can be in parallel, in series with the third and fourth resistances.
8. All 4 resistances can be in parallel.
9. 2 resistors can be in parallel, in series with a third, and this combination in parallel with a fourth.
10. 2 resistors in series, in parallel with a third, this is in series with he fourth

Points 4 and 5 yield the same net resistance, but they are a different combination of resistances, hence we count them as distinct combinations.

Thus, the net number of combinations is 10.

I tried this for 5 resistors as well.

Could someone help in generalizing this for $N$ resistors?

Consider only series and parallel combinations. do not consider bridges.

Or consider them. It's an interesting problem either way

Comment: This looks like http://oeis.org/A000084 originally called *yoke-chains*.

Answer (score 3):

As per the comment, the sequence can be found at [oeis.org/A000084](http://oeis.org/A000084) and are often called Yoke Chains.

The first 1000 terms can be found [here](https://oeis.org/A000084/b000084.txt).

One of the most readable papers on the mathematics of this question is by [Finch, 2003](http://oeis.org/A000084/a000084_2.pdf)

Comment: This just counts the circuits that's in series or parallel, but there are also bridge circuits, so I think there's more.